# Is it common to have no MathSciNet version of a paper in Mathematics?

Tags: citations, mathematics, indexing, review-databases

For papers/books in mentioned in MathSciNet there is a way to get a BibTex version of the citation.

I wanted to cite a paper and it is not in MathSciNet. It is a published paper in  International Mathematics Research Notices in the year 2018. I do not see any reason why it is not in MathSciNet.

Could it be possible that I am not searching correctly?

Is it common to have no MathSciNet version of a published paper in Mathematics?

In case if it helpful (or relevent) I am looking for MathSciNet version of the paper  [Principal Actions of Stacky Lie Groupoids](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/advance-article-abstract/doi/10.1093/imrn/rny142/5049385?redirectedFrom=fulltext). It is not available. I have checked in pages of all three authors of the paper.

Comment: MathSciNet indexes IMRN, and any article from 2018 should certainly already be indexed.  You can try searching different ways (author, title, volume, ...) and if you still don't see it report it to MSN as an omission.

Comment: @Kimball I have added additional information. :)

Comment: So have you reported it as suggested?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, I have reported now..

Comment: In case anyone has an access to https://academic.oup.com/imrn/advance-article-abstract/doi/10.1093/imrn/rny142/5049385?redirectedFrom=fulltext can you tell how do you cite it, with specifying page numbers?

Comment: You can cite it as a preprint, to appear.  If you want you can give the doi.  In any case, journals should take care of finalizing your reference lists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically speaking, the answer to your question is that no, it's not common for a paper not to be indexed. MathSciNet indexes almost all reputable math journals. And I say almost because like all good mathematicians I don't want to make an unproved universal claim, but I don't have any example of a non-indexed reputable math journal in mind.

What is happening here is that the paper you have linked has not been assigned to an issue yet. It is an "advance article", it's available on the publisher's website but it has not been published in print yet. MathSciNet does not index such articles and waits until the paper is formally published to index it. Basically math moves faster than publishers. There is nothing out of the ordinary here.

Since it's been almost two years that the paper has been published online, one can hope it will be formally released soon. From my experience it's a bit long. [IMRN has quite the backlog](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/advance-articles) and their oldest advance article is apparently from April 2018. My guess would be that in June the paper will be assigned an issue and that a few weeks/months later it will appear on MathSciNet. Whether this is good practice on IMRN's part is another discussion.

As for your question on how to cite it, you can write the .bib yourself. It's really not complicated. Another option in this particular case is to click the "Cite" button on IMRN's page. They provide a bibtex file. There are no page numbers, of course, since the article is not part of any issue yet.

Comment: "Another option in this particular case is to click the "Cite" button on IMRN's page" Yes, I copied bib tex file from there. I could not guess there is some thing called advance article. So, I thought there is something wrong as it is not saying any page numbers... Now it is clear...

Comment: "And I say almost because like all good mathematicians I don't want to make an unproved universal claim..." Then why do you claim that the subset of reputable journals not indexed in MathSciNet has measure zero? :)

Comment: @mmeent: I just saw your "Mar 27 '20" comment. In case you didn't know -- your use of :) suggests you might know -- certain events with measure zero can still occur. See [Zero probability and impossibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41107/13130).